# ElasticSearch Match multiple fields, different slops

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a multi_match query. There are 2 fields, and I want the slop to be different for both of them.
Right now the slop is 1 for both, but for bio, I want slop to be 1 and for location, I want slop to be 2. How can I do this?

This is what my query looks like now:

```
{
   "query":{
      "multi_match":{
         "query":"San Diego",
         "type":"phrase",
         "slop":1,
         "fields":[
            "bio","location"

         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "_score":"desc"
      }
   ],
   "size":50,
   "from":0,
   "fields":[
      "id",
      "bio",
      "location",

   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

All a multi match query does is generate match queries, and wraps them in a [dismax query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html).  It's convenient, but if you need to configure each match query differently, you can create this sort of query yourself:

```
"dis_max" : {
    "queries" : [
        {
            "match" : {
                "bio" : {
                    "query" : "San Diego",
                    "type" : "phrase",
                    "slop" : 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "match" : {
                "location" : {
                    "query" : "San Diego",
                    "type" : "phrase",
                    "slop" : 2
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How can I make it so that one of the 2 queries have to match . Both of them do not have to be true.

Comment: That is already the case.  From the linked documentation of dis_max:  "A query that generates the union of documents produced by its subqueries..."